# Display text content when select option is clicked in android

Tags: android

How to display text content from strings.xml when select option is clicked in android? Suppose I have 4 options to select from a dropdown list. If I select one option, how do I display the string corresponding to that option?

Comment: do you have done anything by yourself? if Yes, show code snippet...

Comment: post your code after that all member can help you

Comment: Please  code sharing.

Comment: I have no idea about this one thats why i asked

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by position or by selected item. Try this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(selectedItem.equals("your item name"))
            {
                getResources().getString(R.string.your_string_name);
                 // do your stuff
            }
        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }           
    });
```

Comment: this is only take a single string not a bunch of string bro

Comment: you can access string array for bunch of string @MohammadAli

Comment: ya so who can store a single item in spinner :) you can change your answer and take a array string example :)

Comment: How to relate this string name and select option?

Comment: Using switch statement instead of if clause in your answer to check the value of 'selectedItem' and display the string based on the value will work in this case.